# How to set frame rate in libcamera?

Tags: camera, video-capture

Here I mean the library, NOT the command-line tools such as `libcamera-hello`.

I made a simple program that is mostly same to the one in `libcamera`'s [official tutorial](https://github.com/raspberrypi/libcamera/blob/main/Documentation/guides/application-developer.rst). However, the frame rate is kept to 30 FPS no matter which pixel format/resolution is selected. I even `grep`ped "fps" on the whole documentation and found nothing. How to adjust frame rate in libcamera?

Below is the code piece of calculating FPS. Frames are immediately re-queued when they are finished. FPS is calculated using timestamp in buffer metadata.

```
uint64_t prev_time = 0;

static void requestComplete(Request* req)
{
    if (req->status() == Request::RequestCancelled) return;
    clog << "on req complete" << endl;
    for (const auto& stream_and_buf: req->buffers())
    {
        auto* stream = stream_and_buf.first;
        auto* buf = stream_and_buf.second;
        if (prev_time > 0)
        {
            auto delta_time = buf->metadata().timestamp - prev_time;
            clog << "  stream " << std::hex << size_t(stream) << " buffer " << std::hex << size_t(buf) << " capture at " << std::dec << double(delta_time / 1000000) << endl;
        }
        
        prev_time = buf->metadata().timestamp;
    }

    req->reuse(Request::ReuseBuffers);
    camera->queueRequest(req);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The frame time is controlled by adjusting `Request`'s `FrameDurationLimits` control. It will automatically adjust exposure time or pixel line readout time.

```
std::int64_t value_pair[2] = {lowerMicroSeconds, higherMicroSeconds};
request->controls().set(libcamera::controls::FrameDurationLimits, libcamera::Span<const std::int64_t, 2>(value_pair));
```

The request will be kept using this setting while you resend them.

I don't know if the pair of values are copied inside implementation (it seems not), so I kept the array of two 64-bit integers alive as the whole world.

Comment: That's indeed a good topic to add to the simple-cam application and application guide. Interesting point about the lifetime of the values. That could be looked into indeed, as the Request can be re-used - so Span might cause issues there!

Comment: I think the values should be copied during the call to set() though ... worth verifying.